# Yii2: Display Error Messages when using forms inside Pjax

Tags: error-handling, yii2, rendering, pjax

Is it possible to render a normal view including an UserException/ErrorException?

I cannot interrupt the process with

```
throw new UserException('Error: you did a mistake');
```

because I need to get back some variables in the few. So, therefore, I have to render the view in a normal way like

```
return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
```

Is it possible to create a new UserException like

```
$exception = new UserException('You did a mistake...');
```

and include this in rendering the view?

The problem is, I have a view with a pjax element and

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'You did a mistake...');
```

is not working. So I'm looking for a way to return an Error Message, while keeping the view normally rendered.

Part of the contoller is:

```
        if ($quantity_delivered > $ordered_product_quantity){;
            //throw new UserException('Value is not valid!');
            $exception = new UserException('Value is not valid!');
            //todo return error message with rendering the view
            return $this->render('view', [
                'error' => $exception,
                'model_suppliers_orders' => $model_suppliers_orders,
                'dataProvider_suppliers_orders_products' => $dataProvider_suppliers_orders_products,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: umm.. i cant get what your question is where is the exception occurring? that you are trying to view inside the view can you show some code sample is that a part of the `controller/action` or the `model`

Comment: Hello Muhammad! :-) The exception will be provoced from the controller. If $value1 > $value2 ....return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model,]); In this case I would like to inform the user that the value is not correct.

Comment: Hi @perino can you add a sample code from your controller where you are using the scenario it would be easier to provide a suggested code that way as what i m trying to understand is that is the exception raising automatically that you are trying to show or you are manually raising it ,

Comment: Part of the controller has been added!

Comment: hey did the answer worked out for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually understand in the start but you have a view with `PJAX` wrapper on a form and when you submit the form you want to notify the user if there was an error and `sessionFlash` won't work at this point.

You can make use of the `$this->getView()` to register the javascript from within the controller action, and add errors from the model or any other section you like the view by converting the errors to `json` and then read them using `for in` loop `javascript` I am using a normal `javascript alert()` for the demonstration you can change it to whatever you like.

There is an extension with the name [**`SWEET-ALERT`**](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-sweet-alert) for Yii2 which can become handy for displaying nice user-friendly messages.

I will use `Product` Model for a demonstration which has `name` and `description` field i will only render name field in the form and then submit the form so that it shows me the validation error for the description while trying to save the model.

Your Form should look like below

```
<?php 
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;

?>
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?php 
$form=yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'my-form','action'=>'pjax', 'method'=>'post']);

echo $form->field($model , 'name')->textInput();
echo Html::submitButton('submit');
yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Your **`controller/action`** should look like below

```
public function actionPjax() {
        $model = new \frontend\models\Product();

        if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () )  ) {

            if (!$model->save() ) {

                $result = [];
                // The code below comes from ActiveForm::validate(). We do not need to validate the model
                // again, as it was already validated by save(). Just collect the messages.
                foreach ( $model->getErrors () as $attribute => $errors ) {
                    $result[] = $errors;
                }

                $errors=\yii\helpers\Json::encode($result );
                $script=<<<JS
                        var data=$errors;
                        var msg='';
                        for(error in data){
                            msg+=data[error]+"\\n";
                        }
                        alert(msg);
JS;
                $this->getView()->registerJs($script,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);

            }
        }

        return $this->render ( 'pjax' , [
                    'model' => $model
                ] );
    }
```

Hope this helps you out apart from the above solution if you do not want to show the error messages via `javascript` or you just want to display the model errors you can still use `$form->errorSummary($model)` inside the view and it will automatically display the errors, your action will reduce to the following

```
public function actionPjax() {
        $model = new \frontend\models\Product();

        if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () )  ) {

            if ($model->save() ) {
               //do something else if saved
            }
        }

        return $this->render ( 'my-form' , [
                    'model' => $model
                ] );
    }
```

and your form will look like below

```
<?php 
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;

?>
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?php 
$form=yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'my-form','action'=>'pjax', 'method'=>'post']);

//display model errors
echo $form->errorSummary($model);

echo $form->field($model , 'name')->textInput();
echo Html::submitButton('submit');
yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Muhammad, the problem is that in a pjax view it seems that Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',$exception) is not working! It is not necessary to do an exception, but I don't have no other idea when 1) throw new Exception and 2) setFlash is not working.

Comment: i am not understanding the term pjax view ? @Perino

Comment: In this view, Iam workig with pjax integration to update necessary values. Look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

Comment: hmmm let me see are you using activeForm and do you want to display just this error or want to validate other errors too related model ? @Perino and what ar the chances that you cn move this condition inside model

Comment: updated the answer @Perino see if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: sorry for the late response Muhammad! I was engaged to a different project the last days. I think that your approach is a possibility! It is a kind of work around, but maybe the only way to get the message in the view! thx

Comment: No problem @Perino i can understand, take your time, but this is the right way to do it we dont normally register the script for the view like this if normal for load but `$this->getView()` is for the exact scenario you are facing, where you need to register the script inside the action, i won't call it a workaround. All the best